# Rails Paperclip how to detect image size and handle large images differently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I currently have a 2 megabyte limit on image uploads. Is there a way to detect bigger images (> 2mb) and handle them differently? I want to link to them directly instead of uploading to my app and processing them.

Answer (score 1):

Without uploading to the server, the only way to do it is through javascript and this option is only supported by some browser.

Here is an example using Modernizr to detect the `filereader` property of the browser and with 3 Mb max allowed:

```
var fileErrors = false;
$("input:file#user_photo_picture").change(function (){
    if (Modernizr.filereader){  
        var fileName = $(this).val();
        var sizeInMB = (this.files[0].size / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2);
        $(".file_reference").html(fileName.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''));
        var extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
        if (extension != "jpg" && extension != "png" && extension != "jpeg"){
            $('.new_user_photo').prepend("<div id='error_explanation'> <p>Not valid file</p></div>");
            fileErrors = true;
            return false;
        } else if(sizeInMB > 3){
            $('.new_user_photo').prepend("<div id='error_explanation'> <p>File is too big</p></div>");
            fileErrors = true;
            return false;
        } else {
            fileErrors = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Edit: remember to include Modernizr in your gemfile or manually:

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr

https://github.com/russfrisch/modernizr-rails

Edit 2: Of course, this is jQuery but normally you have it included in your rails project